# How do I stop text from moving an image down in CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css

I need the text just right above the image, like a little title.

I am trying to position text above an image, but every time I use `margin-top: ###px` the image moves down as well. They aren't in the same div element, so why is this happening and how can I fix it?

I kept trying to move the text down using margin-top, but it also moved the image down and I don't know where to go from there.

```css
.column img {
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 160px;
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.column img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.column h2 {
  margin-left: 0px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.column img {
  width: 25%;
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column {
  flex: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.titles h2 {
  margin-left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="titles">
  <h2>Lonoke, AR</h2>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" alt="A field" style="width: 50%" />
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" alt="A forest" style="width: 50%" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Elements are boxes in HTML. By pushing the heading box down you also push the stuff below it down. That said, it's not clear what your goal is. Are you trying to get the text to overlay the images? Please revise to clarify. Does the demo above show the problem?

Comment: Also, if you're not familiar with your browser's document inspector, you should be. It makes many things about your document structure crystal clear.

Comment: Your edit didn't clarify things. "Just like a title" isn't helpful when it comes to specific position and spacing. The text is _already_ like a title.

Comment: Be advised that `.column h2` doesn't select anything in your document. Maybe that's part of the confusion. You also have duplicate rules for `.column img`.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

You have this rule:

```
.column img {
    width: 25%;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-right: 160px;
    transition: transform .2s;
}
```

`margin-top: 150px;` is what's separating your title from the images. Play with that value or just remove it .

Comment: The question strongly implies that the top margin is _desired_.

Comment: I don't know how to understand that, especially when it says "I need the text _just right above_ the image"

Comment: @luenib The OP clearly stated their use of `margin-top`. So I'm not sure your restatement of the fact they are using it adds any value.

Comment: @luenib In other words, OP states that "Every time I do A, B happens." and your answer is "Every time you do A, B happens, so don't do A".

Comment: Yes, you use margin-top *on the title*, and the images will be pushed down too.

Comment: @luenib that point I think is already well understood by OP. I'm just not sure what value restating that in an answer will provide for him.

Comment: Let's wait to see what the OP responds.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what your goal is from your question, but if you want the resizing of the title to be separated from the resizing of the images under it, you can use `position: absolute;` as I've done below. On either the title, the images, or both.

This will effectively layer the objects on top of each other, instead of having them flow one after the other, as you've observed they are doing now.

```css
.column img {
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 160px;
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.column img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.column h2 {
  margin-left: 0px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.column img {
  width: 25%;
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column {
  flex: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.titles h2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="titles">
  <h2>Lonoke, AR</h2>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" alt="A field" style="width: 50%" />
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" alt="A forest" style="width: 50%" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your requirement. You need to give `margin-top` to the text but not the image to bring both of them together and `.column h2` doesn't select anything so I hide it and added the font to the correct selector which is `.titles h2`

```css
.column img {
  width: 25%;
  /* margin-top: 150px; */
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 160px;
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.column img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

/* .column h2 {
  margin-left: 0px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 100px;      
} */

.column img {
  width: 25%;
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column {
  flex: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.titles h2 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="titles">
  <h2>Lonoke, AR</h2>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" alt="A field" style="width: 50%" />
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" alt="A forest" style="width: 50%" />
  </div>
</div>
```